# IStringLocalizer vs resource.designer.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, resx, asp.net-core-localization

I don't really like the idea of injecting localizer, what's wrong with the classic approach of having a class with static properties generated? It's much easier to use than injecting `IStringLocalizer` everywhere I want to localize.

I understand that using this interface allows us to swap the implementation to localize using something other than resources but if we only want to use resources, is it worth the trouble?

Comment: I have the same question as you. The current answer does not really make sense. To elaborate, I see that when I use the Resource file directly, accessing its properties, if someone changes the keys inside the resx files, my classes will throw error. If I use something like `@localizer["Key"]`, no error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, ease of use and speedup of development time.

A shared class with static properties requires to pre-define all localized strings in advance.

But in case of using `IStringLocalizer` you don't have to pre-define the localized strings, you just type plain texts during development, and later on you can define the localized versions in the resource files.

additionally, it will much easier to manage localization with `IStringLocalizer` if you have a team working on the same project.

Comment: actually, I don't have to pre-define anything if I use the generator for resource class.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on why it is easier for a team to manage localization when using `IStringLocalizer` ? note, that at least in WPF Applications, you could just define the default value (what you now pass to `IStringLocalizer` as key), and the localization could be done outside and then later injected via satellite  assemblies. No need for developers to be involved here any further than the default values and the CI/CD pipeline...

Comment: Also, using `IStringLocalizer`, how do you ensure the following: 1) you have a localization entry for every key defined 2) you don't have any entries in resx files which you don't use. When using resource.designer.cs files, 1) fails with a compilation error, 2) is shown in localization tools like Rider/ReSharper provides.